# sending data: MPI_Type_contiguous vs primitive types

Tags: mpi

I am trying to exchange data (30 chars) b/w two processes to understand the MPI_Type_contiguous API as:

```
char data[30];
MPI_Type_contiguous(10,MPI_CHAR,&mytype);
MPI_Type_commit(&mytype);
MPI_Send(data, 3,mytype,1, 99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But the similar task could have been accomplished via :

```
MPI_Send(data, 30,MPI_CHAR,1, 99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I guess there is no latency factor advantage as i am using only single function call in both cases(or is it?).

Can anyone share a use case where **MPI_Type_contiguous** is advantageous over **primitive types**(in terms of performance/ease of accomplishing a task)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One use that immediately comes to mind is sending very large messages. Since the `count` argument to `MPI_Send` is of type `int`, on a typical LP64 (Unix-like OSes) or LLP64 (Windows) 64-bit OS it is not possible to directly send more than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 elements, even if the MPI implementation is using internally 64-bit lengths. With modern compute nodes having hundreds of GiBs of RAM, this is becoming a nuisance. The solution is to create a new datatype of length `m` and send `n` elements of the new type for a total of `n*m` data elements, where `n*m` can now be up to 2<sup>62</sup>-2<sup>32</sup>+1. The method is future-proof and can also be used on 128-bit machines as MPI datatypes can be nested even further. This workaround and the fact that registering a datatype is way cheaper (in execution time) compared to the time it takes such large messages to traverse the network was used by the MPI Forum to reject the proposal for adding new large-count APIs or modifying the argument types of the existing ones. Jeff Hammond (@Jeff) has written a [library](https://github.com/jeffhammond/BigMPI) to simplify the process.

Another use is in MPI-IO. When setting the view of file with `MPI_File_set_view`, a contiguous datatype can be provided as the elementary datatype. It allows one to e.g. treat in a simpler way binary files of complex numbers in languages that do not have a built-in complex datatype (like the earlier versions of C).

Answer (score 2):

`MPI_Type_contiguous` is for making a new datatype which is `count` copies of the existing one. This is useful to simplify the processes of sending a number of datatypes together as you don't need to keep track of their combined size (`count` in `MPI_send` can be replaced by 1).

For you case, I think it is exactly the same. The text from  [using MPI](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/using-mpi) adapted slightly to match your example is,

> When a count argument is used in an MPI operation, it is the same as if a contigous type of that size has been constructed.
>
> ```
> MPI_Send(data, count, MPI_CHAR, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
> ```
>
> is exactly the same as
>
> ```
> MPI_Type_contiguous(count, MPI_CHAR, &mytype);
> MPI_Type_commit(&mytype);
> MPI_Send(data, 1, mytype, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
> MPI_Type_free(&mytype);
> ```

You are correct, as there is only one actual communication call, the latency will be identical (and bandwidth, the same number of bytes are sent).