# Storing values starting from a particular location in MPI_Recv

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I am testing an example, where I am trying to send an array of 4 elements from process 0 to process 1 and I am doing so using MPI_Type_contiguous

This is the code for the same

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    int myrank, size; //size will take care of number of processes 
         
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank) ;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    //declaring the matrix
    double mat[4]={1,   2,  3,  4};
    int r=4;

    double snd_buf[r];
    double recv_buf[r];
    double buf[r];
    
    int position=0;
    
    MPI_Status status[r];
    
    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_contiguous( r, MPI_DOUBLE, &type );
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
             
    
    //sending the data
    if(myrank==0)
    {
       MPI_Send (&mat[0], r , type, 1 /*dest*/ , 100 /*tag*/ , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }   
    //receiving the data
    
    if(myrank==1)
    {
       MPI_Recv(recv_buf, r, type, 0 /*src*/ , 100 /*tag*/, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[0]);
    }
    //printing
    if(myrank==1)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
       {
           printf("%lf ",recv_buf[i]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

As one can see the recv_buf size is same as the size of the array. And the output that is being printed is `1 2 3 4`

Now what I trying to do is that, say the recv_buf size is 10 and I want to store the elements starting from location 6 to 9. For which I have written this code, but to my surprise it is giving no output

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    int myrank, size; //size will take care of number of processes 
         
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank) ;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);


    //declaring the matrix
    double mat[4]={1,   2,  3,  4};
    int r=4;
    double snd_buf[r];
    double recv_buf[10];   //declared it of size 10
    double buf[r];
    int position=0;
    MPI_Status status[r];
    
    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_contiguous( r, MPI_DOUBLE, &type );
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
    //packing and sending the data
    if(myrank==0)
    {
        MPI_Send (&mat[0], r , type, 1 /*dest*/ , 100 /*tag*/ , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }   
    //receiving the data
    if(myrank==1)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&recv_buf[6], r, type, 0 /*src*/ , 100 /*tag*/, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[0]);
    }
    //printing
    if(myrank==1)
    {
       for(int i=6;i<10;i++)
       {
           printf("%lf ",recv_buf[i]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37341323/1366871) one can read:

> MPI_Type_contiguous is for making a new datatype which is count copies
> of the existing one. This is useful to simplify the processes of
> sending a number of datatypes together as you don't need to keep track
> of their combined size **(count in MPI_send can be replaced by 1)**.

That being said, in your `MPI_Send` call:

```
MPI_Send (&mat[0], r , type, 1 /*dest*/ , 100 /*tag*/ , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

you should not send an array with 'r' elements of type 'type', but rather send 1 element of type 'type' (which is equal to 4 doubles). One of the goals of the `MPI_Type_contiguous` is to abstract away the `count` to 1 instead of keeping track of the number of elements.

The same applies to your recv call:

```
MPI_Recv(&recv_buf[6], 1, type, 0 /*src*/ , 100 /*tag*/, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[0]);
```

Finally, you should also free the custom type accordingly:

```
MPI_Type_free(&type);
```

The entire code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int myrank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank) ;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    double mat[4]={1, 2, 3, 4};
    int r=4;
    double snd_buf[r];
    double recv_buf[10];
  
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_contiguous( r, MPI_DOUBLE, &type );
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
             
    if(myrank==0)
       MPI_Send (&mat[0], 1 , type, 1, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else if(myrank==1)
    {
       MPI_Recv(&recv_buf[6], 1, type, 0, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
       for(int i=6;i<10;i++)
          printf("%lf ",recv_buf[i]);
      printf("\n");
   }

   MPI_Type_free(&type);        
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

**The Output:**

```
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
```